# How to insert a value into a H2 DB timestamp column with format yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss?

Tags: java, spring-boot, migration, h2, flyway

I am trying to insert into a H2 database timestamp column using Flyway migrations. My goal is to save a date with the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss
```

but I got this error message:

[image]

Besides, I am using :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also I have application-properties file as follows:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:~/capitole
spring.datasource=capitole
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false

# This is for FlyWay configuration
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:~/capitole
spring.flyway.schemas=capitole
spring.flyway.user=sa
spring.flyway.password=
```

I create my table of this way:

V1_1__init.database.sql

```
drop table if exists PRICES;
create table PRICES (
    Id            int       not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    brand_id      int       not null,
    start_date    TIMESTAMP   not null,
    end_date      timestamp  not null,
    price_list    int       not null,
    product_id    int       not null,
    priority      int       not null,
    price         double    not null,
    curr          varchar(50)   not null
);
```

And the second migration is to the insert:

```sql
insert into PRICES(brand_id, start_date, end_date, price_list, product_id,priority,price,curr)
values (1,
        parsedatetime('2020-06-14-00.00.00','yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss'),
        parsedatetime('2020-12-31-23.59.59','yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss'),
        1,
        35455,
        0,
        35.50,
        'EUR');
```

So when I run the application I get the error message shown previously.

So I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Fix your code formatting. Either indent all lines by four spaces *or* wrap in a pair of three back-ticks.

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider using the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Your apparent approach of trying to determine the last moment of the year is problematic. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

Comment: thanks but now it is not possible to edit. there are many requests to edit queued. But I don't think it will affect the understanding at all.

Comment: Use `HH` for the 24-hour clock (hours 0-23), and `hh` for the 12-hour clock (hours 1-12 with "am" or "pm"). See [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: I just change this way: parsedatetime('2020-06-14 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'). But the result is the same.

Comment: Just an observation: The date string in your question (`2020-06-14-00.00.00`) does not match the date string in your comment (`2020-06-14 00:00:00`). Which one are you actually using in the code you execute? Make sure your formatting string matches that. Also, please add the related error message as formatted text, not as a screenshot. You should be able to [edit] your own question (surprised to read that you were not able to do that - that sounds odd...).

Comment: I am using this: 2020-06-14-00.00.00. But you know I'm doing a test and I've tested it in various ways. but it is the first way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to "go with the flow" and use a [supported datetime format](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#date_and_time):

```
2020-06-14 00:00:00
```

From the example SQL file it seems that you are using hardcoded values, i.e. you are not using an SQL dump in the format you mentioned. In this case the effort to use different format is minimal.

But if you are using a rather large number of preexisting timestamps, the best approach would be to create a simple utility tool that would "parse" the input file, reformat the timestamps, and output it to an output file. You could use the `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}` regex to locate the timestamps, and for each timestamp invoke this method:

```
String fixFormat(String timestamp) {
  return timestamp.substring(0, 10)
      + " "
      + timestamp.substring(11).replaceAll("\\.", ":");
}
```